# Want more control over ReplicatedMergeTree parts merging in clickhouse

Tags: partitioning, clickhouse

Lets say we're using this table:

```
create table table1 (
  ingestion_time DateTime,
  ingestion_day Date,
  dim1 String,
  met1 double, ...
)
engine=ReplicatedMergeTree(...),
partition=(ingestion_day)
order by = (...);
```

We have a usecase where we need to create new part every 15 mins and then for a running window (lets call it update window), possibly delete and recreate certain 15 minute parts.

For example if the update window is 15 days, i can on 2020-10-20 can choose to delete the part for 2020-10-15 23:45 and re ingest it.

If i partition by 15 minute interval, it would quickly lead to too many partition problem and so i am looking for a way to have fine grained control over parts merging in MergeTree where i can keep the 15 minute parts intact in the update window maybe manually call to merge the older parts into daily partitions.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? I couldn't find any settings that let me control parts merging, though there are settings that i can use for retention of older parts that have merged.

Answer (score 1):

Merging is not manageable, it occurs in the background at an unknown time, so you can’t plan for it. There is [OPTIMIZE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/optimize/)-statement to initialize an unscheduled merge that finishes eventually.

---

Theoretically, it can be defined the arbitrary partition size, including 15 minutes. But it can be a bad way, it depends on the concrete case.

```sql
..
PARTITION BY toStartOfFifteenMinutes(ingestion_time)
..
```

to avoid the error "Too many partitions for single INSERT block" need to increase the limit of parameter [max_partitions_per_insert_block](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity/#max-partitions-per-insert-block).

And remove the outdated partition(s) by call [DROP PARTITION](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/partition/#alter_drop-partition).

---

As an alternate way can be considered using [mutations](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/#mutations) to delete outdated rows, but it is usually an ineffective and not recommended way.

---

Look at [ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/) or [ReplicatedCollapsingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/collapsingmergetree/) to deduplicate/collapse data by CH means.

---

A retention policy can be defined on a column or table level by [TTL](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-ttl)-clause.